# ESENT information

Tags: event-log, app

Our RMM software keeps alerting us to a device going offline. Each time this ESENT error has been lingering around it. Can anyone help me figure out what this means and how to figure this out?

```
Description
------------
Raven (10812,T,97) 40-fZXwc-C:\ProgramData\DinerwareGiftServer\DinerwareGiftServer\1.0.0.0\DinerwareGiftDatabase\Databases\DinerwareGift\Data: The database engine stopped the instance (1). 
 
Dirty Shutdown: 0 
 
Internal Timing Sequence: 
[1] 0.000013 +J(0)
[2] 0.000072 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:0, WS:-8K # 0K, PF:-4K # 0K, P:-4K)
[3] 0.000023 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:0, WS:-12K # 0K, PF:-44K # 0K, P:-44K)
[4] 0.000013 +J(0)
[5] 0.031337 -0.014088 (6) WT +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:9, WS:16K # 0K, PF:-32K # 0K, P:-32K)
[6] 0.000027 +J(0)
[7] 0.000009 +J(0)
[8] 0.023244 -0.005877 (11) WT +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:4096/2) +M(C:0K, Fs:8, WS:-16K # 0K, PF:-28K # 0K, P:-28K)
[9] 0.001052 -0.000173 (1) WT +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:66/1) +M(C:0K, Fs:2, WS:8K # 0K, PF:20K # 0K, P:20K)
[10] 0.000167 +J(0)
[11] 0.002289 -0.000222 (2) WT +J(0)
[12] 0.000009 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:0, WS:-4K # 0K, PF:-4K # 0K, P:-4K)
[13] 0.004993 +J(0)
[14] 0.000034 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:0, WS:-12K # 0K, PF:-32K # 0K, P:-32K)
[15] 0.000004 +J(0).

Details
------------
Log Name: Application
Source: ESENT
Event ID: 103
Level: Information
User: null
Task Category: General
Logged: 6/29/2023, 12:00:16 AM
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think what I'm asking is what does this error mean and why does it keep triggering an offline alert? Is it shutting down or is it because of a faulty internet connection? We know that they have an unreliable internet connection, but if we can rule out the computer actually shutting down, we can continue with network troubleshooting.

Comment: The error is "The database engine stopped an instance". One possibility is that the server has run out of disk space, mostly for Windows Update.

Comment: @JoshuaJimenez - Check the Windows Event Logs on the device itself. All the error you provided, suggests, is that a connection was dropped. [The actual error log of the MSSQL instance might be helpful.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1100549/error-fix-(database-engine-service-failed-in-sql-s)

Comment: If it's a RavenDB, it might just be timing out because no one's accessing it (because it's offline/internet down/etc). There is a timeout setting here `Raven/Tenants/MaxIdleTimeForTenantDatabase`, but it's likely just be a symptom